# How to write add method for validating only gmail?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation in my application for client side, Any ideas to add customized method to validate on gmail.

Comment: What do you mean by "validating gmail"?

Comment: gmail id validation in the input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (/@gmail\.com$/.test(string)) 
{ // This is a gmail id. }
```

Comment: this is plain JavaScript. the "string"variable is the email you''re testing. that regex returns true if "string" contains "gmail"